# Custom Post Type Author limit

Tags: wordpress, limit, custom-post-type, author

It's possible limit creation of custom post type named "ofertas" to 1? Only for authors.

I have installed Wordpress 3.8 and plugins don't work (Limit Post Creation 1.4, Bainternet Post Creation Limits 3.1 and Custom Post Limits 3.6).

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what do you want actually but you can limit your post through this code:-

```
<?php query_posts($query_string.'limit=1');  ?>
             <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          //your stuff

    <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

[You can see more loop here](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)